# Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I get the following error in the function below:

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

`In` doesn't work here. What can I do?

```
delimiter $

create function pricesTax()returns decimal(8,2)
begin
    declare y decimal(8,2);
    declare z decimal(8,2);
    declare M decimal(8,2);

    set y = (select PR(Prices) from Products);
    set z = (select Prices from Products);
    set M = y*z;

    return M;
end $

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your queries return more then one row, so you should `limit` your results:

```
set y = (select PR(Prices) from Products limit 1);

set z = (select Prices from Products limit 1);
```

or more probably, rethink your trigger in a proper way.

Comment: In this case isn't there a substitution to -in- clause where it can work inside a function because I want more than one result??

Comment: the error is related  to some   select that return more then a row and you are trying to assing  these results (more then one)  to a var  .. that accept  only one value ... so probably you must rethink to you trigger  ..